# CodeIgniter: How to get input from View and use it in the controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, view, controllers

I'm quite new to CodeIgniter (using PHP). So right now I have a textbox on my webpage where visitors are requested to enter in their names. I take in a name (i'll use the variable $username for it) and I want to save it in a database I have. I am wondering how I can do that. Do I somehow pass $username to a function in the Controller and then pass that value to my Model? Thank you very much, a simple example would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>controller/save" name="form">
  <label>User Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="Username">   
  <input type="submit" value="Add"/>
</form>
```

in controller

```
function save
    {
    $arrData["Username"] = $this->input->post("Username");
    $this->User_model->Add($arrData); 
    }
```

in User_model

```
function Add($arrData) { 
        if($this->db->insert(tableName, $arrData))
          return true;
        else
          return false;
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much!! i just got it to work, your example is great! thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search brings up the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html). You should take a look at it.

The example they give:

```
$data = array(
   'title' => 'My title' ,
   'name' => 'My Name' ,
   'date' => 'My date'
);

$this->db->insert('mytable', $data);
// produces: INSERT INTO mytable (title, name, date) VALUES ('My title', 'My name', 'My date')
```

Comment: he asked for an example that demonstrates passing data from a view to a controller and then storing it

Comment: No, he asked _Do I somehow pass $username to a function in the Controller and then pass that value to my Model?_ Seems like a question to me.

Comment: This is a half answer. The title and the question explicitely says, how to pass data  from view to controller. The $username variable here is arbitry and he has no idea where it will come from (hence the title)

Comment: I was more trying to know how to pass the variable from the view to the controller. but thanks for the help anyway. and... it's a she...