# How to get autocomplete value from view to controller Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I am beginner with codeigniter, and MVC method too.

I have some questions: 

My autocomplete is work properly, but i want to print value from view with my controller, 

ex: `echo $emp_name << $emp_name` is value from textbox in view (with textbox id="emp_name")..

This is the javascript in my view:

```
<!-- autocomplete -->
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var site = "<?php echo site_url();?>";
        $(function(){
            $('.autocomplete').autocomplete({                    
                serviceUrl: site+'furlough/autocompletes',                    
                onSelect: function (suggestion) { 
                 $('#emp_name').val(''+suggestion.emp_name);                                   
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

This is my  script:

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('furlough/dor'); ?>" method="post" >
                    <div class="wrap" style="margin-top:10px;">
                        Employee Name :<br><input type="text" name="txtbox_empname" value="" style="font-size:14px; width:440px;" class='autocomplete nama' id="emp_name" placeholder = "Please insert employee name..."/>  
                        <br />
                        <input type="submit" value="Process" name="btn_process">                                
                    </div>
</form>
```

So, what should I do?
Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for this thread [CodeIgniter: How to get input from View and use it in the controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14764458/codeigniter-how-to-get-input-from-view-and-use-it-in-the-controller)

This method solved my problem:

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('furlough/dor'); ?>" method="post" >
    <div class="wrap" style="margin-top:10px;">
        Employee Name :<br><input type="text" name="txtbox_empname" style="font-size:14px; width:440px;" class='autocomplete nama' id="emp_name" placeholder = "Please insert employee name..."/>   
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Process" name="btn_process">                                
    </div>
</form>
```

Just give name to my textbox (which i want to get the values, the ex is: txtbox_empname) and post to my controller, the ex is:

```
<?php echo site_url('furlough/dor'); ?>
```

and in my controller (furlough.php):

```
function dor() 
    {
        $print = $this->input->post("txtbox_empname");
        echo $print;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the required value as a function parameter in autocomplete, and user that in controller.